# trouble with private messaging

Tags: php, node.js, socket.io

***Kindly Note:*** I know this might be a possible duplicate of other questions but i'd like help with my code!!

I'm trying to build a chat feature for my social network..I've used node.js and socket.io ...The prob with this code is that, the message is being delivered to every connected user instead of just the targeted to_user...The source of this code is from thenewboston tutorials...
I've built it as of now like this:

***client.php***

```
<div class="chat" hidden>
    <textarea class="chat-name"><?php echo escape($data->username); ?></textarea>
    <div class="chat-messages">
    <?php 
     $chtrndr = $cht->renderchats(escape($data->id));
     foreach ($chtrndr as $chtrndrs) {
       echo '<div>' . $chtrndrs['m_from'] . ': ' . $chtrndrs['m_text'] . '</div><br>';
     }
     ?>
    </div>
    <textarea class="chat-textarea" placeholder="Type your message"></textarea>
    <div class="chat-status">Status:<span>Idle</span></div>
    </div>
    <!-- <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> -->
    <script src="http://127.0.0.1:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="server.js"></script>
    <script>
    (function(){
      var getNode = function(s) {
        return document.querySelector(s);
      },

      //get required nodes
      status = getNode('.chat-status span'),
      messages = getNode('.chat-messages'),
      textarea = getNode('.chat-textarea'),
      chatName = getNode('.chat-name'),
      statusDefault = status.textContent,

      setStatus = function(s) {
        status.textContent = s;

        if(s!==statusDefault)
        {
          var delay = setTimeout(function(){
            setStatus(statusDefault);
            clearInterval(delay);
          },3000);
        }
      };

      setStatus('testing');

      try {
        var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8080');
      }
      catch(e)
      {
        //set status to warn user
      }

      if(socket!==undefined)
      {
        //listen for output
        socket.on('output',function(data){
          if(data.length)
          {
            //loop through results
            for(var x=0;x<data.length;x=x+1)
            {
              var message = document.createElement('div');

              message.setAttribute('class','chat-message');
              message.textContent = data[x].m_from + ': ' + data[x].m_text;

              //append
              messages.appendChild(message);
              messages.insertBefore(message, messages.firstChild);
            }
          }
        });
        //listen for a status
        socket.on('status',function(data){
          setStatus((typeof data === 'object') ? data.message : data);

          if(data.clear === true)
          {
            textarea.value = '';
          }
        });
        //listen for keydown
      textarea.addEventListener('keydown',function(event){
          var self = this,
            fname = <?php echo escape($_SESSION['user']); ?>,
            tname = <?php echo $data->id; ?>;

          if(event.which === 13 && event.shiftKey === false) {
            socket.emit('input', {m_from:fname, m_to:tname, m_text:self.value});
            event.preventDefault();
          }
        });
      }
    })();
    </script>
```

And this is the server file:
***SERVER.js***

```
var client = require('socket.io').listen(8080).sockets;
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mysql  = require('mysql');
var path = require('path');
var dbconn = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '',
  database : 'test'
});

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, './css/')));

app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

    dbconn.connect(function(err){
        if(err){
    console.log('Database connection error');
  }else{
    console.log('Database connection successful');
  }
        client.on('connection',function(socket){

          console.log('Data received from Db');

            sendStatus = function(s){
                socket.emit('status',s);
            };

            //wait for input
            socket.on('input',function(data){
                var fname = data.m_from,
                    tname = data.m_to,
                    m_text = data.m_text,
                    whitespacePattern = /^\s*$/;

                if(whitespacePattern.test(m_text))
                {
                    sendStatus('message is required');
                }
                else
                {
                    var record = { m_from: fname, m_to:tname, m_text: m_text };
                    dbconn.query('INSERT INTO messages SET ?', record, function(err,res){
                     if(err) throw err;

                        client.emit('output',[data]);

                        sendStatus({
                            message: "message sent",
                            clear: true
                        });
                    });
                }

            });
        });
    });
```

i wud like to add the following functionality:
*(a)*Since it is a social network, it shud be capable of serving private chats, betn 2 logged in users...
*(b)* The messages shud be received by the receiver after he logs back in at a later time..

I've combed many pages on google n SO already and heard that **rooms** are my go-to. But being a noob in nodejs, idk how to implement the rooms to make private messaging possible...
If any1 cud help me code it or even set me on the right path, frm where i can learn to code in node.js with easy tutorials for beginners, it wud b a really gr8 help!! Thanx in advance!

Comment: javascript is client-side, if you're planning on releasing this or taking it off localhost - or even for better practice - learn to use PHP to do the database queries and just use an AJAX request in something like jQuery.. you could look into [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: _"help me code it"_. SO is _not_ a free coding service. Other than that, asking for tips about tutorials or other off site resources is _off topic_ for SO. Read more here: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Magnus, saying help me code it doesnt necessarily mean that im asking ppl to code for me..all i want is assistance...Im not asking any1 to code afresh..I already have code to build on...And, the above code is based on a set of tutorials, thats all.. im not asking tips on off-site topics :)

Comment: It's hard to take: _"cud help me code it"_ in any other way than that you're asking for code. _"where i can learn to code in node.js with easy tutorials for beginners"_ is asking for off site tutorials, no? If you have nodejs-code that you're having issues with, post the _relevant_ parts in your question and tell us what _specific_ problem you're facing. As it is now, your question is _way_ to broad.

Answer (score 0):

Look it should be like every user in your application should have **unique id**

**LOGIC**

1.you have to emit the event from your backend(server side) on **output_userId**

2. Your frontEnd (client side) should listen to the socket event on **output_userId**

what this will do is like you are emitting the message for the specific user from server side and every user will be listening on **output_userId** which is their specific id. where **userId** is there unique id of the project.

example:

we have 3  users 
1,2,3

now if user 1 is sending message to user 2

your events should be like

Server Side

Socket.emit(output_1)

client side

every client side user should listen to their output_userid

for user 1 it should be output_1

for user 2 it should be output_2

for user 3 it should be output_3

Comment: tnq fr ur response...my doubt is this: I have unique user id for each user obtained frm php...Bt, how do i get it into node.js and also how do i assign the user id to the respective chat?

Comment: node have nothing different for this its socket.io same in node as in php.
you can do it this way => when your user is sending the message from client side take the userId of the user who is sending message, to whom message is send, message which is been sent and use them to store the data on the data base and emit socket event to other user as i told you in above answer

Comment: so the code fr this for user2 as receiver wud b like: socket.emit('msg',output_2_id)  ? where i'd get output2_id from the client side ??

Comment: no it should be socket.emit(output_2_id,'message') 1st argument is the variable on which client side be listening.

Comment: oh.i'll try it out n rply...tq fr ur response